# Spring Boot jersey getting 404

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, jersey

I am trying to create a webapp but it's not working I am geeting 404 response.
The package structure is like:

com.example.demo

com.example.demo.jerseyConfig.java

com.example.demo.demo.java

com.example.demo.backend.service.userManagementService.java

My Application.java is

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

import com.example.pentest.backend.service.userManagementService;

@SpringBootApplication
public class demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //new demo().configure(new SpringApplicationBuilder(demo.class)).run(args);
        SpringApplication.run(demo.class, args);
    }
}
```

My Jersey config is

```
    package com.example.demo;
    
    import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
    import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
    import com.example.pentest.backend.service.userManagementService;
    
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
    
    @Component
    @ApplicationPath("/")
    public class jerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {
        public jerseyConfig() {
            register(userManagementService.class);
        }
    }
```

My userManagementService.java is

```
package com.example.demo.backend.service;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.FormParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;

import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;

@Component
@Path("/backend")
public class userManagementService {

    @Path("/user/login")
    @GET
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public Response createUser() {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).build();
    }
}
```

I am running it on tomcat server, I am seeing no errors. The url I am trying to access is `http://localhost:8080/demo/backend/user/login`

Comment: Is there any reason for opting jersey instead of spring fest APIs?

Comment: show us the URL your trying to access. (full path)

Comment: You could really use Spring Rest instead of jersey actually. since it comes out of the box.

Comment: Why just simply use `Spring-Boot` default features? Also by following the Java naming convention, you classes names should be in `CamelCase`.

Comment: Try changing to @ApplicationPath(value="/*") in Jersey config. Notice I added * wildcard.

Comment: Can you explain why you are using `/demo` in the URL?

Comment: @Paul demo is the name of the webapp

Comment: Unless you configured this, demo should not be in the path.

Comment: @PaulSamsotha when we have multiple webapps in tomcat, then we run it like this.

Comment: But you’re not running multiple applications in an installed Tomcat. You’re running an SE application with an embedded server.